# When I try to add a new node to the list, I get error message "no matching function call"

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to write a function that will add to polynomial terms with equivalent exponent values together, and put that term in a new linked list. I know my logic for doing this isn't correct yet, but I would at least like to see that I can add the new term into the new list. Every time I try to do this though, I get the error message `no matching function call to Polynomial::Term::Term`

Here is the function I am trying to write. I get the error on the line where I am setting head equal to a new term.

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+( const Polynomial &other ) const
   {
       double sum;
       shared_ptr<Polynomial> result = shared_ptr<Polynomial>(new Polynomial()); // where you are going to store your results
       shared_ptr<Polynomial::Term> a = this->head;
       shared_ptr<Polynomial::Term> b = other.head;

       while(a != nullptr && b != nullptr)
       {
           for(a; a != nullptr; a=a->next)
           {
                for(b; b!=nullptr; b=b->next)
                {
                    if(a->exponent == b->exponent)
                    {
                        sum = a->coeff+b->coeff;
                        head = shared_ptr<Term>(new Term( sum, exp, head ));

                    }

                }

            }
       }
```

header file

```
#ifndef H_POLYNOMIAL_H
#define H_POLYNOMIAL_H

#include <ostream>   // to be able to declare overloaded << operator as a friend
#include <string>    // input type to the main constructor
#include <tr1/memory> // for shared_ptr
#include <tr1/shared_ptr.h>

using namespace std;


class Polynomial
   {
   friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &, const Polynomial & );

   public:
      Polynomial();             // default polynomial is empty (= 0)
      Polynomial( string & );   // Set the polynomial according to the string

      Polynomial &operator=( const Polynomial & );   // assignment

      bool operator==( const Polynomial & ) const;   // equality test
      bool operator!=( const Polynomial & ) const;   // not equal test

      Polynomial operator+( const Polynomial & ) const;   // addition

      double eval( double x ) const ;   // evaluate the polynomial at x

   private:
      class Term   // a Term of the polynomial
         {
         public:
            Term( double c, int e, shared_ptr<Term> n );
            double coeff;       // the coefficient
            int exponent;       // the exponent
            shared_ptr<Term> next;
         };

      shared_ptr<Term> head;    // The head of the list
      static double TOL;        // Tolerance for floating point equality
   };

#endif
```

class implementation

```
Polynomial::Term::Term( double c, int e, shared_ptr<Term> n )
   {

   coeff = c; exponent = e; next = n;

   }

//+--------------------------------------+
//| Default Constructor: Polynomial is 0 |
//+--------------------------------------+
Polynomial::Polynomial()
   {
   head = nullptr;
   }

//+-------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Constructor: The input string contains coefficient-exponent |
//| pairs where everything is separated by whitespace           |
//+-------------------------------------------------------------+
 Polynomial::Polynomial( string & str )
   {
   stringstream ss( str );  // stringstream lets us extract items separated by
                            // whitespace simply by using the >> operator
   double coefficient;      // to hold the coefficient
   int exp;                 // to hold the exponent
   head = nullptr;          // initialize head to null

   // read in coefficient-exponent pairs and add each term to the list
   // ----------------------------------------------------------------
   while (ss >> coefficient >> exp)
      if (coefficient != 0)   // don't make a 0 term
         head = shared_ptr<Term>(new Term( coefficient, exp, head ));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you haven't declared a variable `exp` when you try to use it in

```
new Term( sum, exp, head )
```

I guess you meant `b->exponent` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you don't declare the `exp` variable and that you seem to have some confusion over value semantics, this is invalid:

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+( const Polynomial &other ) const
{
    //...
    head = shared_ptr<Term>(new Term( sum, exp, head ));
}
```

This assignment is invalid because the function is marked `const`, so `head` is a `const std::shared_ptr`. You probably don't want a mutating `operator+`, so I'd recommend copying the `Polynomial` and operating on that. Preferably by defining an `operator+=` and implementing in terms of that on a copy of the data.

Comment: But even if I try to copy the polynomial, wouldn't that require making a new Polynomial object?

Comment: Yes it would. I think that creating a copy is far preferable to `a+b` modifying `a`.

Comment: `operator+` should also be a non-member function so that it works with implicit conversions on the left-hand-side.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators).

Comment: thank you for the link. I am just thoroughly confused with how I would go about copying the Polynomial object. Especially if I am having problems right now calling the Term constructor to create a new term.

Comment: Write a constructor with the signature `Polynomial (const Polynomial& rhs)`